# Disable keyboard arrow navigation in a ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, keyboard

I have a ListView and I am trying to disable the keyboard navigation between individual items.
I tried to set KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None" to the ListView, to its PanelTemplate and also to individual items. None of it worked.

Also, the keyboard directional navigation is messed up - the panel is a wrappanel and pressing the arrows navigates chaotic, sometimes it also cycles just between two children with no chance of jumping to other ones with the arrows. That is why I want to disable, though correcting it would be even better.

Here is the relevant code:

```xml
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                   Width="210" 
                   Margin="0,12" 
                   KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Width="24" 
                Height="24" 
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Black" 
                BorderThickness="1 1 1 1" 
                Margin="0"
                KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False" 
                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" 
                       FontSize="20" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       x:Name="textBlock" 
                       FontFamily="Verdana, Arial"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: use KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None" into listboxitem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a handler for the PreviewKeyDown event:

```cs
private void listView1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Left:
        case Key.Right:
        case Key.Up:
        case Key.Down:
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```